# Javascript doesn't work for javascrip_inlcue-tag Rails 3.2.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following the demo_app in [Michael Hartl's book Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorail](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app?version=3.2#top). The demo is a simple Scaffold User name:string email:string

I'm getting an error in my **application.html.erb** file:

```
Errno::EINVAL in Users#index 
Showing ~/demo_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised: 
Invalid argument - cscript //E:jscript //Nologo //U /tmp/execjs20120323-4388-1an85xw-0.js 2>&1
(in ~/demo_app/app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee)

3: <head>
4:   <title>DemoApp</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
```

if I chnage line #6 to:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "default" %>
```

The program will run perfectly except it won't allow me to delete users (presumably because it's not running the javascript).

Environmental info:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i386-cygwin]

$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.2
```

Content of ~\demo_app\app\assets\javascripts\users.js.coffee:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
```

Content of ~\demo_app\app\assets\javascripts\application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Post your `users.js.coffee` file.

Comment: Can you post the contents of app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee. Also ensure you are following the version of the book for Rails 3.2 - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2

Comment: john, confirming that I am following version=3.2.

Comment: content of user.js.coffee posted above.

Comment: please post your application.js and the files in your app/assets/javascript folder.

Comment: Link to repo has been added. How can I post the application.js (sorry if I haven't done the right thing here).

Comment: Contents of application.js posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to uncomment **gem 'therubyracer'** and run **bundle**, and also it's better to use last stable version of ruby

Comment: I removed the commenting on therubyracer and bundle install ran into an issue with the libv8 gem. Error: "An error occured while installing libv8 (3.3.10.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.3.10.4'` succeeds before bundling."

Comment: to unstall libv8: git clone git@github.com:fractaloop/libv8
cd libv8
git submodule update --init
bundle install
bundle exec rake compile

Comment: Said, even though I've got the program working ok, should I still follow your suggestiong of uncommenting the gem therubyracer and uninstalling libv8?

Comment: ooop, i thought that u'r having problem with installing libv8, if it's installed successully, then u can skip the previous step, so Errno::EINVAL in Users#index has gone ?

Comment: Yes, the Errno: EINVAL has dissapeared.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but can't vote it up (don't have 15 reputation points). Once I do I'll come back to it and vote up.

Answer (score 0):

I searched around for other questions that discussed the gem therubyracer. I found one answer that suggested what Said Kaldybaev had suggested here. That didn't work for me. But there was another suggestiong to remove the code

```
//= require_tree .
```

from the app/assets/javascripts/application.js file.

Deleting that code made the application work (including the destroy function).